# Unable to configure custom VirtualHosts in xampp

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, xampp

I'm editing `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

I've added VirtualHost directive to this file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerAdmin kirzilla@gmail.com
    ServerName rem
    DocumentRoot "/home/kir/www/rem/public"
    ErrorLog logs/rem-error_log
    CustomLog logs/rem-access_log common
    <Directory "/home/kir/www/rem/public">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
      AllowOverride None
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I've created directory `/home/kir/www/rem/public 0755 kir:kir`

Then I've added `127.0.0.2 rem` to `/etc/hosts/`.

Then I've restarted xampp `sudo /opt/lampp restart`

When I'm trying to enter `http://rem` I'm being redirected to `http://rem/xampp`
As I figured out redirect is produced by file which can be found at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php`; this file redirects us to `/xampp` directory.

Please help me to figure out why DocumentRoot directive (and, probably other directives too) are ignored and Apache considers `/opt/lampp/htdocs` as DocumentRoot.

Thank you.

UPDATED: xampp is running apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!

Including of `httpd-vhosts.conf` was commented in `httpd.conf` :)